# How to generate pdf in python with pandas and reportlab

Tags: python, pdf, generate

I am trying to export a list of sqlite table in pdf with pandas and reportlab. When I print everything looks good, but when I try to generate pdf I get only headers row but as column format. Because is part of larger application I have a little GUI to generate pdf. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

```
class Example(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)            
        self.parent = parent       
        self.initUI()               
    def initUI(self):    
        self.parent.title("Pdf_test")                  
        self.grid()
        self.label = Label(self.parent, text = 'Pdf test')        
        self.label.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.buton = Button(self.parent, width= 15, text=" PDF ", command=self.pdf_test)
        self.buton.grid(row=1, column=0)

    def pdf_test(self):

        self.conn = sqlite3.connect("Baza_Date.db")
        self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()
        with self.conn:
            self.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM test1")
            rows = (pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM test1", self.conn))
            print (rows)
        report = canvas.Canvas("Multi.pdf")     # save pdf in working folder)   
        report.setFont("Times-Roman", 20)
        report.setFillColor(black)       
        size = 9
        y = 650
        for row in rows:
            report.setFont("Helvetica", size)
            report.drawString(70, y, row)
            y = y - 10                
        report.save()
```

Comment: In ReportLab, you need to create a table. I don't see that in this code.

Comment: check out the guide here: https://www.reportlab.com/docs/reportlab-userguide.pdf

Comment: Thanks for replying, I started to read